# State structure when using "react-redux-form"

Tags: reactjs, redux, react-redux

I have a form with these fields, "name" and "email". I am using "react-redux-form" package.

In my reducer I have the following code

```
initialState = {
  name: '',
  email: ''
}

const myReducer = (state, action) => {
  return modelReducer('model', initialState)(state, action)
}
```

This works fine, but I'd like to add a dropdown and hold it's possible values in the state. Is it OK if I add these values to the state, so the code would look like this?

```
initialState = {
  name: '',
  email: '',
  options: []
}

const myReducer = (state, action) => {
  let newState = modelReducer('model', initialState)(state, action)

  switch (action.type) {
    case RECEIVED_OPTIONS:
     newState = {
       ...newState,
       options: action.options
     }
     break
  }

  return newState
}
```

The code does work, but it seems wrong to do it this way. What would be a better alternative?

Comment: Presuming `modelReducer` comes from the `react-redux-form` package, and you don't want to fork their code, then this looks like a great way to do it in my opinion.  One of the great things about redux is that reducers can nest/cascade if you need them to.

Answer (score 0):

Have a look at the `modeled` reducer enhancer: https://davidkpiano.gitbooks.io/react-redux-form/content/model_reducers.html#using-existing-reducers